# How to extend custom BaseRepository with Mikro ORM EntityRepository

Tags: typescript, mikro-orm

I am trying to create a `BaseRepository` with custom methods that every repository should have. I have created my custom repository and extended it with EntityRepository but I get TS warning when trying to map the data to `JSON`.

This is the BaseRepository

```js
import { AnyEntity, EntityName, EntityRepository, FilterQuery, SqlEntityManager } from '@mikro-orm/core';
    
export default abstract class BaseRepository<T extends AnyEntity<T>> extends EntityRepository<T> {
  protected readonly resource: string;
    
  protected constructor(_em: SqlEntityManager, entity: EntityName<T>) {
    super(_em, entity);
  }
    
  async listRecords(query: any, page: number, perPage: number) {
    try {
      const [results, count] = await this.findAndCount(
        <FilterQuery<any>>{},
        {
          limit: perPage,
          offset: (page - 1) * perPage
        }
      );
    
      const mappedData = await Promise.all(
        results.map(entity => {
          // THIS IS THE ERROR
          return entity.toJSON();
        })
      );
    
      return {
        rows: <EntityDTO<T>[]>mappedData
      };
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

In the `return entity.toJSON()` I get the following error:

```
TS2339: Property  toJSON  does not exist on type  Loaded<T, never>
```

And this my custom repository

```js
export default class UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User> implements IUserRepository {
  protected readonly resource = 'users';
    
  constructor(protected readonly _em: SqlEntityManager) {
    super(_em, User);
  }
    
  async listUsers(query: ListUsersQuery) {
    const userEntities = await this.listRecords(query.filters, query.page, query.perPage);
    
    return new UserCollection(userEntities.rows, userEntities.meta, userEntities.links); // Assuming UserCollection class exists
  }
}
```

How can I adjust my types for the `BaseRepository` so typescript wouldn't complain about the method not existing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `toJSON` method on `AnyEntity` interface, so that's probably why. That method is actually also not present on the ORM `BaseEntity` anymore in v6, you don't really need it (neither you need to call it, it's called automatically when you serialize something via `JSON.stringify` which happens on higher levels, e.g. in some web server).

Also, there is no reason for your `Promise.all` call, the methods are sync.

I'd suggest you use `wrap().toJSON()` instead:

```
  async listRecords(query: any, page: number, perPage: number) {
    try {
      const [results, count] = await this.findAndCount(
        <FilterQuery<any>>{}, // this cast is probably not needed
        {
          limit: perPage,
          offset: (page - 1) * perPage
        }
      );
    
      const mappedData = results.map(entity => {
        return wrap(entity).toJSON();
      });
    
      return {
        rows: <EntityDTO<T>[]>mappedData // neither this one
      };
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Absolute boss! Thank you. Still learning about this epic ORM! although this casting is needed for some weird reason 

 <FilterQuery<any>>{}, // this cast is probably not needed.

Comment: Be sure to check out the new getting started guide then!

Comment: https://mikro-orm.io/docs/next/guide